# Computing gradient twice for two different losses in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, gradient

I want to compute the gradients twice for two different losses in the same iteration.

Code:

```
batch_output0,batch_output1 = get_output_from_model(model=model,
                                         data=batch[0])       
train_loss0 = loss_fun0(batch_output0, batch_labels0.float().view(-1, 1)) 
train_loss0.backward()       
grad0_conv_w = model.conv1.conv1.weight.grad

    
batch_output0,batch_output1 = get_output_from_model(model=model,
                                         data=batch[0])        
train_loss1 = loss_fun1(batch_output1, batch_labels1.float().view(-1, 1))
train_loss1.backward()        
grad1_conv_w = model.conv1.conv1.weight.grad
```

Outputs:

```
train_loss0: tensor(0.6950, grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward>)
train_loss1: tensor(25.5431, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
Grad0: tensor([-2.4883e-05,  3.7842e-05,  1.2635e-04,  ..., -1.6413e-04,
     -1.8419e-04, -1.7884e-04])
Grad1: tensor([-2.4883e-05,  3.7842e-05,  1.2635e-04,  ..., -1.6413e-04,
    -1.8419e-04, -1.7884e-04])
```

You may note that even though the two losses are quite different, the gradients for the corresponding losses are exactly the same.

Please help me to diagnose the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't figure out the exact reason, but I suggest checking two things: 1) Check gradient values are exactly the same at the end of the decimal point at all spatial positions. 2) Confirm your model has no operation that prevents gradient (less probable). Additionally, you don't need to fed same inputs twice, just call `loss1.backward(retain_graph=True)` followed by `loss2.backward()`. This might solve your problem since I checked the gradients differs in my local environment.

Comment: Why back propagate twice? You can simply sum up the two losses and back propagate once.

Comment: As for `loss0` and `loss1` being identical, can you place `loss1` before `loss0` and try again? Also, did you print the grad right after backward or after the whole code block?

Comment: @ihdv I had printed the gradients after the whole code block. Printing gradient after calling the .backward() each time, giving different gradient values. But I don't understand why it happened. I stored each gradient in a separate variable and then printed them at the end of the code block.

Comment: @ROHANGUPTA python doesn't work like C++. You are not storing `model.conv1.conv1.weight.grad` to `grad0_conv_w` and `grad1_conv_w`. Instead, they are different names for the same tensor. In (not strict) C++ terms, everything in python is a "reference".

Comment: @ihdv can you please tell me how to store the gradient values in python? I need to use them later.

Comment: @ROHANGUPTA You can use `grad0_conv_w = model.conv1.conv1.weight.grad.clone()`. This copies the data to a new tensor called `grad0_conv_w`